# AT+BIA command format

Tags: android, bluetooth, at-command

I am sending AT+BIA=0,0,0,0,0,0,1 command to android phone. But I am getting response as "ERROR". So I would like to know the format of AT+BIA command. Am I using the correct format? How do we know the correct format?

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What does `AT+CIND=?` return?

Comment: `+CIND: ("service",(0-1)),("call",(0-1)),("callsetup",(0-3)),("callheld",(0-2)),("signal",(0-5)),("roam",(0-1)),("battchg",(0-5))` This is the output of AT+CIND=? command

Comment: I do not think `AT+CIND` is relevant for this question.

Comment: `AT+BIA` is not a (3GPP) standard command, you need to find a formal document describing it, preferably your manefaturer's AT command documentation. Is it supported at all by your phone (check if it is listed in the output of `AT+CLAC`. Or run the test command `AT+BIA=?`)?

Comment: Both the commands are returing "ERROR". I connected to hands-free profile and sending these commands.

Comment: Can someone help me on this? I tried sending the same command to different mobile phone which is from different manufacturer but still I get ERROR. Atleast it would be great if I get detailed error details.